# SQL UPDATE table with OPENXML

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I want to UPDATE a table within the following OPENXML statement but don't know where to put the syntaxes as UPDATE, FROM and WHERE.

I get a nice resultset with the OPENXML statement but how do I UPDATE a table with it?

```
DECLARE @x xml

SELECT @x=R
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\Users\ronal\Dropbox\Projecten\Voormelden Portbase\20161021095457591.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS XMLPortbase(R)

DECLARE @hdoc int
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hdoc OUTPUT, @x


    UPDATE [COMTECdefault].[dbo].[voormelden] 
SET 
    Tarcode = '12345678'

FROM OPENXML (@hdoc, '/StandardBusinessDocument/documentContent/contentBody/Acknowledgement/messageStatus',3)
WITH (
        previousContentReference varchar(50) '../../../previousContentHeader/contentReference',
        messageAcceptanceCode varchar(50) '../messageAcceptanceCode',
        timeslotReference varchar(50) '../timeslotReference',
        offeredArrivalDateTime DateTime '../offeredArrivalDateTime',
        offeredDepartureDateTime DateTime '../offeredDepartureDateTime',
        messageStatusCode varchar(255),
        messageStatusDescription varchar(255),
        additionalStatusRemarks varchar(255),
        containerPrefixAndNumber varchar(50) '../containerPrefixAndNumber'
    )
WHERE ID = previousContentReference

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hdoc
```

Comment: `FROM OPENXML` with the accompaining procedures to prepare and to remove the document is outdated. It is much better to use the *real* XML methods `.value()`, `.nodes()`, `query()`, `.exist()` and `.modify()`. Please poste a (reduced) example of your XML in order to help you.

Comment: Hi Ronald! As you are new here (Btw: Welcome!) please allow me one hint: Is this question solved? Do you need further help? Please allow me one hint: If this question is solved, it would be very kind of you, to tick the acceptance check below the (best) answer's vote counter. This will 1) mark this issue as solved 2) make it easier for followers to find the best solution 3) pay points to the answerer and 4) pay points to you. Once you've crossed the 15 points border yourself, you are  - additionally - asked to vote on contributions. This is the SO-way to say thank you. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what kind of `UPDATE` you're trying to do, but I believe this would match records in a table `someTable` on `contentReference` and update the `messageAcceptanceCode` and `messageStatusCode` values in the table from the XML:

```
UPDATE someTable
SET someTable.messageAcceptanceCode = XMLdata.messageAcceptanceCode,
    someTable.messageStatusCode = XMLdata.messageStatusCode
FROM OPENXML (@hdoc, '/StandardBusinessDocument/documentContent/contentBody/Acknowledgement/messageStatus',3)
WITH (
        contentReference VARCHAR(50) '../../../contentHeader/contentReference',
        messageAcceptanceCode VARCHAR(50) '../messageAcceptanceCode',
        messageStatusCode VARCHAR(255)

    ) XMLdata
WHERE someTable.contentReference = XMLdata.contentReference
```

If you need a more detailed answer, it would be handy to have the schema for the table you want to update, the structure of your XML and ideally some example data for both.

Comment: Hi,

First of all thanks for the responses.

I've got it workign accept for the WHERE clause.

It seems there is no value in it.

Comment: Hi,

First of all thanks for the responses.

I've got it working accept for the WHERE clause.

It seems there is no value in it. I'm sure that there is a value in de xml. And if I check the resultset without an UPDATE statement I can see the value.

What am I doing wrong?

....

WHERE ID = ContentReference

Comment: Could you provide example data from your XML file and table to help troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

My magic glass bulb tells me that you want to reach something like this:

### Attention:

Try this first with `SELECT` instead of the `UPDATE ... SET` (and remove the `YourTable.` to get correct column aliases)!

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET YourTable.ContentReference     =nd.value(N'(../../../contentHeader/contentReference)[1]',N'varchar(50)')
   ,YourTable.MessageAcceptanceCode=nd.value(N'(../messageAcceptanceCode)[1]',N'varchar(50)')
   ,YourTable.MessageStatusCode    =nd.value(N'.',N'varchar(255)')
FROM @x.nodes(N'/StandardBusinessDocument/documentContent/contentBody/Acknowledgement/messageStatus') AS A(nd)
```

If performance matters, this `../../../` is **very slow**. But without an example of your XML it is hardly possible to suggest something.